How to use SQLCMD in ARM64 architecture?
I am using NVIDIA Jetson Orin nano board (which is based on ARM64 architecture) to as an IoT Edge device to deploy Azure Edge modules from Azure marketplace.
I have deployed the temperature sensor and SQL Edge module modules inside the board, and they are running perfectly.
But when I am going inside the SQL Edge container to connect using sqlcmd (using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql-edge/connect) I can't find it.
So, I searched the official documentation and found out that SQL client tools are not available on ARM64 platform.
So is there a solution to how we can use sqlcmd?
mssql@e0f0035b988c:/$ /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P '<YourPassword>'
bash: /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd: No such file or directory


Azure SQL Edge is no longer supported on ARM64 (also noted in the documentation), however, when it was supported it was explicitly noted in said documentation (archive.org) that sqlcmd was not part of the install:

sqlcmd is not available inside the ARM64 version of SQL Edge containers.

You could, therefore, install a different tool, such as go-sqlcmd, which does support ARM64, or (likely better) migrate to a supported platform now that support has been removed.

Can go-sqlcmd be installed on the docker container?

Yes, it can be @HeyHello , hence why I suggested it

But I can't install it inside the docker container. Its showing error.

Ahh, then address that error... I can't help you with that, as you haven't shared you attempt(s), or error(s).
